# GridView's RowsAdded event is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, .net-4.0, bindingsource

I have a GridView which contains columns **Code, Experience, Salary, Bonus**

Data for **Code**, **Experience** and **Salary** columns come from `BindingSource` and I need to calculate data for **Bonus** based on **Experience** and **Salary**.

So I have created `RowsAdded` event for the `DataGridView` and added the following code

```
int index = employeeBindingSource.Position;
Employee emp = (Employee)employeeBindingSource.Current;
double bonus = (emp.Experience < 4 ? 0.08f : 0.12f) * emp.Salary * 12;
employeeDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = bonus.ToString("0.00"); //setting value for bonus column
employeeBindingSource.MoveNext();
```

But I get Bouns for only two rows.

[image]

So I commented the code inside this event and created another event `RowStateChanged` added the above code and it works fine.

[image]

What is the problem with the `RowsAdded` event ? And is `RowStateChanged` the correct event to calculate the bonus column ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are heading in wrong direction.

Would it be easier, yet more correct from design point of view to add extra fields to you data source.
If you data source is a list of typed objects, you could just add a property only with getter.

```
 public decimal Bonus
 {
     get { return (Experience < 4 ? 0.08f : 0.12f) * Salary * 12; }
 }
```

If you data source is `DataSet/DataTable` you can add a calculated column.

Comment: Where should I add this property? Should I add it in the Employee class? And my datasource is list of typed objects.

Comment: @Searock - yes, I think so. But can't tell for sure, as I don't know what your `Employee` class exactly does. If `Salary` is a property of `Employee` class, then `Bonus` also should belong to it.

Comment: I wish I could do it, but I'm not the author of the Employee class, so I don't have the option of adding a property.

Comment: @Searock - you can always make a wrapper around the `Employee` class. It will still be better than managing business logic in UI.